# Unable to upgrade ovirt-3.6 to ovirt-4.0 in CentOS 6.8

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos, dependencies

Trying to upgrade using a command `yum update "ovirt-engine-setup*"` detailed link is [here.](http://www.ovirt.org/release/4.0.0/)

`Error: Package: ovirt-engine-lib-4.0.1.1-1.el7.centos.noarch (ovirt-4.0)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: ovirt-engine-dwh-4.0.1-1.el7.centos.noarch (ovirt-4.0)
           Requires: apache-commons-collections
Error: Package: otopi-java-1.5.1-1.el7.centos.noarch (ovirt-4.0)
           Requires: apache-commons-logging
Error: Package: otopi-1.5.1-1.el7.centos.noarch (ovirt-4.0)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@base/$releasever)
               python(abi) = 2.6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

I have both python `2.6` and `2.7` and as a default, it is linked `python2.7` using `alias`. But still there is a error saying requires `python(abi) = 2.7`

Tried all these possible [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=requires%20python(abi)%20%3D%202.7) questions. But problems are not resolved.

Comment: Your link http://www.ovirt.org/release/4.0.0/ is about RHEL 7 , CentOS 7. ( And Fedora.) ... Note : `requires python(abi) = 2.7` means no **rpm package** python-2.7 available or installed. I.e. the rpm package base has only information about rpm packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Ovirt's website:

> oVirt 4.0 is intended for production use and is available for the
>   following platforms:
>
> - Fedora 23
> - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2 or later
> - CentOS 7.2 or later
> - Scientific Linux 7.2 or later

So Centos 6.8 isn't supported officially so even if you get it running it will be a pain to update. Ideally you can bring up a new VM on 7.2 and migrate the engine to the new host.

Answer (score 1):

please follow http://www.ovirt.org/documentation/migration-engine-3.6-to-4.0/ for upgrading from 3.6 el6 to 4.0 el7.

If you're on hosted engine also read https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/how-to/hosted-engine/#migrate-the-engine-vm-from-36el6-to-40el7

Thanks